# Dedupe Array of Strings in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a final array of Url I **scraped** from a webpage but cannot seem to remove duplicates. Tried using set and got hashable error.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

links = []

no_hash =[]
full = []
final = []
no_dupe = []
dupe = []
final2 = []
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        links.append(link['href'])

for i in range (len(links)):        
    if (links[i][:1]) not in ["#"]: no_hash.append(links[i])

for i in range (len(no_hash)):
    if (no_hash[i][:1]) == "/": full.append("https://www.census.gov"+no_hash[i])
    else: full.append(no_hash[i])

for i in range (len(full)):
    if full[i].endswith('/'): final.append(full[:-1])
   

for i in range (len(final)):
    if final[i] not in no_dupe: no_dupe.append(final[i])

    
        
pd.DataFrame(no_dupe).to_csv("desktop/task_2.csv")
```

I expect to create a csv of only unique url

Comment: instead of `for i in range (len(final)):` you can use `for item in final:` and then use `item` instead of `final[i]`. It will be more readable. The same with other `for`-loops.

Comment: use `print()` to check values in variables and which part of code is executed. It helps to find problem.

Comment: to get unique values in column `df['column name'].unique()`

Comment: I see what you did there. I updated with item as you said and found the missing else statement. It works!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have used this before and it worked:

```
fullArray = ["some", "data", "to", "store", "to", "later"]
finalArray = []
dupes = []
for item in fullArray:
    if item not in finalArray:
        finalArray.append(item)
    else:
        dupes.append(item)
```

And then as usual, print the arrays to test:

```
print(finalArray)
print(dupes)
```

And you should see that any duplicates have been sent to the dupes array instead of the finalArray. 
EDIT: missed an else statement